# Java graphics2d: Verify if point is contained in region

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm creating a java desktop application that draws a map in a JFrame designing a country at a time.

After closing the region `region.closePath();` I need to know if a point is inside the region last drawn.

In JavaScript, there was the element canvas2d the `function isPointInPath(x, y)`.

Is there something similar in java Graphics2D?

Comment: Sorry! I expressed myself poorly. It's a  desktop application. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation i was using the setTransform method.

So, to contains method works correctly, i had to convert the point to the correct proportion of matrix.

Like that:

```
reg.contains(x / this.Matrix[0], y / this.Matrix[3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. There's a contains(x,y) method for the region.

Comment: Yes! the contains method worked! In my situation i was using setTransform. I had to convert the point to the correct proportion of matrix. Like it reg.contains(x / this.Matrix[0], y / this.Matrix[3])